Converting an 24bppRGB memory to 32bppRGBx memory
I have an IntPtr pointing at a memory segment that stores pixel sequence in RGB888 format, so the length of this segment should be width * height * 3 bytes. I want to convert them to an byte array of pixels in RGB888x format, in other words, in a format every 4 elements in this array reprents a single pixel that the value of the last element doesn't matter.
Is there an efficient approach to achieve what I described?
I'm using .Net standard 2.0, so Span is available.
I'm currently using the code below :
int length = width * height * 3;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < length; ofs++)
    {
        ms.WriteByte(Marshal.ReadByte(pointer, ofs));
        if (ofs % 3 == 0)
        {
            ms.WriteByte(255);
        }
    }

    return new RawImageData()
    {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        ColorType = SKColorType.Rgba8888,
        Data = ms.ToArray()
    };
}

Update 20240813 10:20:00 GMT
According to @500 - Internal Server Error's suggestion, the code now is
int length = width * height * 3;
var buffer = new byte[length];
Marshal.Copy(pointer, buffer, 0, length);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    for (var offset = 0; offset < length - 3; offset += 3)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, offset, 3);
        ms.WriteByte(byte.MaxValue);
    }

    return new RawImageData()
    {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        ColorType = SKColorType.Rgba8888,
        Data = ms.ToArray()
    };
}


What aspect of efficiency are you referring to? Development efficiency or execution efficiency?

@shingo More efficient than using a for loop to read and copy elements to a new byte array maybe?

@shingo Actually I'm looking for suggestions, I believe there's some better approach out there.

@JonasH I have attached the code I'm currently using.

Are you sure that your data is in exactly the format that you state? BMP has every line padded to a multiple of 4 bytes so that each line starts off aligned to a 4 byte boundary. My suggestion would be to work in int or int64 taking 3 at a time with the padding logic hardwired. If you really don't care what goes into x then for int it becomes out[0] = in[0]; out[1] = (in[1]<<24)+(in[2]>>8); out[3] = in[3] <<8;. This trick can be generalised to SIMD instructions processing 16, 32 or 64 bytes at a time. Working in bigger chunks reduces loop overhead. Benchmark to find the sweet spot.

@MartinBrown I'm pretty sure, the data is not read from an bmp file, it's written to memory by a dll of a camera SDK.

Marshal.ReadByte() and ms.WriteByte() will both slow you down quite a bit compared to using arrays of byte directly. On the reading side you can use Marshal.Copy to move everything to an array in one go before converting the format.

In that case my suggestion ought to work subject to big/little endian adjustments. If you want to duplicate code above then or them with | 0xff to set the padding byte. The trick is to fetch and store data all aligned and use shifts to make the awkward mixed value(s). If you don't care about the pad byte then it saves a cycle to skip it.

This is the code I'm currently using
public static unsafe void Bgr24ToBgra32(
    byte* source,
    byte* target,
    int sourceStride,
    int targetStride,
    int width,
    int height)
{
    Parallel.For(0, height, y =>
    {
        var sourceRow = source + y * sourceStride;
        var targetRow = (uint*)(target + y * targetStride);

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            var sourceIndex = (sourceRow + x * 3);
            var s = *((uint*)sourceIndex);
            s = s  | 0xff000000;
            targetRow[x] = s;
        }
    });
}

It uses raw pointers and is therefore unsafe. You could probably do something similar with Span<T> or Memory<T> if you prefer safe code. It also uses unaligned reads that do have a speed penalty. So there are almost certainly faster implementations, especially once you start consider SIMD.
But I would expect it to be a fair bit faster then your posted code. As always you should do some benchmarking to confirm.
Note that there are some confusion regarding RGB vs BGR, both names are sometimes used to describe the same actual order, I believe this is due to endianess issues. Also note that this puts the Alpha after the color values, if you need it in front you might need to do something like s = (s << 24)  | 0x000000ff instead.
